# Nuclear physics, relativity theory and quantum mechanic on Astronomy SE

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions about nuclear physics, relativity theory and quantum mechanics on topic?
I'm asking this because I'm trying to send a question about relativity theory on SE. But I don't know where can I send this - on Astronomy SE or on Physics SE?

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: I think generally those would be better on Physics SE. Some relativity questions may be welcome here, but nuclear physics and quantum mechanics (except as they relate to cosmic principles such as stellar fusion and black holes) are pretty firmly Physics SE territory.

Comment: If you had a specific question or line of questioning in mind, you can edit your meta question above to highlight that and I think we could get you a more definitive answer.

Comment: @called2voyage No, I haven't got a specific problem or question.

Comment: I think physics would be better